Excel Return True if exists in list
Hi all I need to return a True in the result column if TRUE exists in either record 1 2 or 3.
Have tried If =AND etc.
Thanks


You could do =NOT(AND(NOT(RC[-3]:RC[-1]))) if you desperately want to use AND. But =OR(RC[-3]:RC[-1]) is easier.

Try using the following formula :


=BYROW(A2:C5,LAMBDA(α,OR(α)))


Using ETA LAMBDA() it is relatively shorter as well:
=BYROW(A2:C5,OR)


Or, Simply use OR() function and fill down:
=OR(A2:C2)



Wouldn't just using OR be a simpler approach?

Yes ofcourse, I have shown all approaches.

But you haven't shown a suitable OR() approach (which my answer does). Your OR() solution is not a row-level formula, but a range-level formula. I'm not sure why your answer was accepted and mine was voted down.

I dont know who downvoted your answer, while there is nothing wrong in my answer also.

Assuming record1 is A1, record2 is in B2, etc, then the below cell references will work, otherwise adjust accordingly.
Put this in the D2 column (where the FALSE is below the Result heading)
=OR(A2, B2, C2)

Then drag down. The numbers will update for each row.
edited due to comment by Enigmativity.
Originally, this post had the logic fully expressed as such:
=IF(OR(A2 = TRUE, B2 = TRUE, C2 = TRUE), TRUE, FALSE)


=IF(OR(A2 = TRUE, B2 = TRUE, C2 = TRUE), TRUE, FALSE) just simplifies down to =OR(A2, B2, C2)
